# E/GoogleCertificates: Failed to load com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

I have this exception when loading my google maps: E/GoogleCertificates: Failed to load com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates                                                                                               pt: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

here is the content of my build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.proper_international.properinternationnal"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.owlike:genson:1.4'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}

















apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: It's because either your device or emulator has an out-dated version of Google Play services. Update play services and this will go away.

Comment: thank @lakshman.pasala